# Action Link not currently directing to controller action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have view same like facebook group. If the User not currently joined the group it is showing **JOIN** button.
I have used this line for calling joinCommunity() action from button

```
<button>@Html.ActionLink("Join", "joinCommunity", new { id = @Model.Community.CommunityID })</button>
```

but it is not directing to the joinCommunity() action in my controller.
here is my function in controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult joinCommunity(int CommID)
    {
        var UseriD = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault().Id;
        var newUser = new CommunityUser()
        {
            UserID = UseriD,
            CommunityID = CommID
        };
        db.CommunityUsers.Add(newUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View("Community");
    }
```

I am not getting (breakpoint) hit on this function.

Comment: Where is the breakpoint?
You have a mismatch with parameter name Id and CommId.
Are you using ......beginForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action's type is `[HttpPost]`. But ActionLink creates `<a>` elements which are used for `[HttpGet]`.

Try removing `[HttpPost]`.

But if that spesific action is for posting purposes, leave that attribute there and create another action for `[HttpGet]`.

If you want to post the data, not get, don't use ActionLink. Add a form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("joinCommunity", "[CONTROLLER_NAME]", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="CommID" value="@Model.Community.CommunityID" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Join" />

}
```

Comment: @UzairNadeem I am glad if this worked. You should check HTTP Request Types at some point. This is the very basics of web applications and not spesific to Asp.Net. Also you'd better mark this post as answer for further visiters' benefit.